# Binding ViewModel to View through View ctor makes Maui app crash

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui, .net-maui

When I launch my app I get the following message:

> An unhandled win32 exception occured in MauiApp.exe

Unfortunately I am not able to get a detailed exception message, as the application crashes and "the debugger is not configured to debug this unhandled exception". I have isolated the issue and it occurs whenever I bound my View to a ViewModel like so:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = mainViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}

public sealed class MainViewModel
{
   
}
```

And in the MauiProgram.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: first, if you've narrowed it down to that section of code, add a `try/catch` to catch the exception.  You can also configure VS to break on unhandled exceptions.  Second, try setting the `BindingContext` **after** you call `InitializeComponent`

Comment: There is a connection that occurs to the database.  What is the connection string?  Often the connection string will fail to database will fail.

Comment: Is your ViewModel class declared in the same file as your view? I would recommend to place the ViewModel in a separate .cs file and also swap the `InitializeComponent();` and `BindingContext = mainViewModel;` statements.

Comment: With a breakpoint on `BindingContext = mainViewModel;`, is `mainViewModel` null? If so, add to MauiProgram.cs:  `builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();`, if it is not there already.

Answer (score 1):

Put the creation, after initialization:

```
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = mainViewModel;
```

Comment: And you swapping those two lines of code will cause a crash? Are you sure?

Comment: @H.A.H. I've seen WPF apps crash because specific controls were not initialized (or created) when the attempt to bind active data to them, couldn't get a proper reference and threw and exception. So, in certain circumstances it can avoid a crash.

Comment: You can, say put BindingContext= new object() or null, and it will still not crash. Changing those 2 lines doesn't break the binding also. Worst case scenario, your commands and properties wont be working right.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code on my side and I found the issue.
You should add the following codes in the `MauiProgram.cs` file, not only register the `MainViewModel` but also register the `MainPage`.

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
```

Comment: "Tested the code" what the OP provided was really basic, is there an issue in Maui that needs to be resolved or a documentation issue which needs to state this to new people?

Answer (score 0):

My ViewModels

1. are all partial classes.
2. Inherit or annotate ObservableObject.

Show me your main page XAML.

(BindingContext set to something funny line new object(), or null... wont cause such crash. I'm 99.99% sure that there is something in your XAML that is causing the InitializeComponents() to fail)